# Javascript/Typescript pushing into array and adding to Record asynchronously

Tags: javascript, typescript, list, asynchronous

I thought this would have a trivial answer online, but couldn't find it. Is the following safe in terms of the array and Record being populate considering it's being operated on asynchronously? I'm doing it for performance reasons:

```
async fun(elementIds: string[]): void {
    const idsNeedingMoreThingsToBeDone = [];
    const idsToData: Record<string, number> = {};
    await Bluebird.each(elementIds, async (elementId) => {
       const data = Redis.get('cache/${elementId}'); // time consuming async process on id
       if(data) {
           idsToData[elementId] = data; // Is this safe?
       } else {
           idsNeedingMoreThingsToBeDone.push(elementId); // Is this safe
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: one question - why are your functions `async` if you never `await` - that makes no sense at all - and if `Redis.get('cache/${elementId}')` is a "time consuming async process on id" how do you expect `data` to have a useful value synchronously?

Comment: if you dont await your API call the code continues executing, which means no, your data obj will not be populated. You either need to add an await in front of 'Redis' or wrap your if statement in a '.then()' method

Comment: I'm missing the await. Corrected

Comment: `redis.get()` would also not give you a result without a callback or await. Is your redis client promise or callback based?